# Color de Menu Hamburguesa NavigationView Android

Tags: java, android

Actualmente mi menu se ve negro como la siguiente imagen

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y me gustaria que fuera blanco mi xml es el siguiente :

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="330dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer"
    android:background="@color/white"
    app:itemIconTint="@color/black"
    />
```

El back end es el siguiente

```
    public void MenuConfiguracion() {
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.actionbar_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.bringToFront();
        drawer.requestLayout();


        final ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();
        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        navigationView.bringToFront();
        navigationView.requestLayout();
}
```

La verdad no me doy cuenta donde setea este color , ya probe cambiando en mi THEME , de Light ah DarkLigth  como vi en algunas preguntas pero no me funciono ,

Agrego nuevo style

```
<style name="AppThemeMenu" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>

</style>
```

en el XML

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="330dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:theme="@style/AppThemeMenu"
    app:itemIconTint="@color/black"
    />
```

Comment: Ese icono no se encuentra realmente en el Drawer, sino en el app_bar. Supongamos que el  layout de la barra de herramientas se llama   `app_bar_main.xml`. Entonces le puedes poner el estilo `AppBarOverlay` para que se vea en blanco. Por ejemplo: `<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">` El estilo `AppBarOverlay` es uno de los estilos por defecto, que deberás tener en `styles.xml`.  También, puedes crear el tuyo propio por supuesto.

Comment: de no tenerlo al estylo , necesito algo en especial para que ande o solo colocando el nombre deberia tomarlo?

Comment: De no tener ese, es muy probable que tengas algún otro estilo que te convenga. Ese es uno de los estilos que Android Studio crea por defecto. Si tú cambias, cuando pongas el punto después de `AppTheme` (me refiero a la última línea, en esta parte `android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"`), te va a mostrar varios estilos, si no está ese, prueba con alguno de los que te aparecen. Ese tipo de cosas conviene hacerlas con estilos y no darle color manualmente al icono directamente.

Comment: voy a intentar cedano si funciona te pido que publiques como respuesta asi te la acepto ! muchas gracias por tomarte el tiempo de responder , eres muy amable

Comment: Intenta primero y comenta el resultado. Estamos para ayudar en lo que se pueda. Saludos.

Comment: Eh editado mi pregunta con lo que agrege y aun asi aparece en negro

Comment: @BrunoSosaFastTag es una imagen , un drawable el icono?

Comment: Yo jamas utilze un icono para ese icono del menu hambuerguesa  , para mi es un icono que aparece magicamente y nose como cambiarlo , en realidad solo quisiera cambiar el color

Comment: @BrunoSosaFastTag que tema tiene definido el Activity que carga el NavigationDrawer en el manifest.xml ?

Comment: En mi manifest tengo declarado android:theme="@style/AppTheme"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Una opción es definir el color en un estilo, dentro de `styles.xml` (pueden existir varios en tu proyecto), agregas el estilo con nombre `DrawerIcon` y defines el color blanco:

```
<style name="DrawerIcon" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle">
    <item name="spinBars">true</item>
    <item name="color">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```

posteriormente revisa que tema usa la Activity que contiene el `NavigationDrawer` dentro de tu `AndroidManifest.xml` (`android:theme="???"`)y agrega a este tema el estilo `DrawerIcon`.

Por ejemplo si ti aplicación usa el estilo `AppTheme` entonces aquí debo definir el estilo `DrawerIcon` :

```
  <style name="AppTheme">
        ...
        ...
        ...

        <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerIcon</item>

  </style>
```

En base a lo anterior puedes cambiar sin problema el color del icono de la "hamburguesa":

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: lo pondre en practica Jorge,  muchisimas gracias ! , pruebo y vengo a comentarte! aunque con estos ejemplos seguro que anda

Comment: lo que no entiendo es eso del manifest en la clase osea mi clase esta declarada asi en el manifest <activity android:name=".Home"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">

        </activity>

Comment: no entiendo como agregar ese <item >

Comment: @BrunoSosaFastTag si <activity no tiene declarado un tema revisa <application, el tema que define ahí es en el que tienes que agregar el  <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerIcon</item>

Comment: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.

Comment: @BrunoSosaFastTag espera no debes agregar un tema en el androidManifest.xml , debes buscar si tu Activity tiene definido uno, si no es así puedes agregar uno y definirlo mediante android:theme= por ejemplo : <style name="AppTheme">
        ...
        ...
        ...

        <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerIcon</item>

  </style>

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73446/discussion-on-answer-by-jorgesys-color-de-menu-hamburguesa-navigationview-androi).

Answer (score 1):

A mi me funciona sobre escribiendo el color de texto secundario en el tema del toolbar

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
android:id="@+id/toolbar_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
app:theme="@style/mi_estilo"
app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
app:titleTextColor="@color/colorEncabezados"
app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">
```

Este va en styles.xml

```
<style name="mi_estilo" parent="AppTheme">
<item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

Comment: lo intente pero sin exito

Comment: Pero donde defines android:textColorSecondary ? @AlvaroFabianM

Answer (score 0):

lo primero es identificar cual es el estilo que arraga tu `ToolBar` o el activity donde esta el `ToolBar`y colocar esta linea

```
<item name="colorControlNormal">@color/black</item>
```

Fuente

https://www.flipandroid.com/cmo-cambiar-el-color-del-icono-de-la-hamburguesa-en-el-diseo-del-material-cajn-de-navegacin.html